# removing # from the words in c# using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

i Want to read file  which has "#" attach to word i want to remove this from words
**Input File**

```
a, 00001740, 0.125, 0,     able#1
a, 00001740, 0.125, 0,     play#2
a, 00002098, 0,     0.75,  unable#1
```

i want this in  the following formats that have no **#**
**Output Should be this**

```
a, 00001740, 0.125,  0,      able
a, 00001740, 0 .125, 0,      play
a, 00002098, 0,      0.75,   unable
```

i write the following code

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("D:\\output.txt");
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("D:\\input.txt"); 
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Regex expression = new Regex(@"\b\w+(?=#\d*\b)");
                    var results = expression.Matches(reader.ToString())
                    foreach (Match match in results)
                    {


                        tw.Write(match);

                    }
                    tw.Write("\r\n");
                }
                tw.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }
            textBox1.Text = "";                    
        }
    }
```

Comment: May be you can replace `#` and remove trailing digits..

Answer (score 1):

use `Regex.Replace()`

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "#.*", "");
```

- [Regex.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write that to some other file, because you're rewriting the file while you're reading the original file's content, if you don't want to read and cache the whole content of the file.

Also, consider this example:

```
int index = line.IndexOf("#");
if (index != -1)
{
    line = line.Substring(0, index - 1);
}
```

Here you don't have to deal with regexes, thus this will run much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole code can be replaced with 3 lines:

```
string txt = File.ReadAllText("D:\\input.txt");
txt = Regex.Replace(txt, "#.*?(\r\n|\n|$)", "$1");
File.WriteAllText("D:\\output.txt", txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex replace is probably the best bet here.

```
 File.WriteAllLines("c:\\output.txt", File.ReadAllLines("c:\\input.txt").Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "#.*","")));
```

Or possibly `TakeWhile`

```
File.WriteAllLines("c:\\test24.txt", File.ReadAllLines("c:\\test.txt").Select(line => new string(line.TakeWhile(c => c != '#').ToArray())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as per my comment:

```
        string s = "a, 00001740, 0.125, 0,     able#1";
        string m = Regex.Replace(s, @"#\d$", ""); 
        //for more than one digit  @"#\d+$"
        Console.WriteLine(m);
        Console.ReadLine();
```